# How to use $.each conditionally in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, each

I have an array vm.settings.tab_permissions,in that if role is equal to vm.heading i have to replace it with vm.data if not role i want to push vm.data to vm.settings.tab but with my code duplicates are getting inserted,i know i wrote wrong.Can anyone help me.Thanks.

```
 $.each(vm.settings.tab_permissions,function(i, v){
 if(v.role === vm.heading){
              v = vm.data;
            }else {
             vm.settings.tab_permissions.push(vm.data);
            }
          });
```

Comment: in angular don't use `$.each ` use `angular.foreach`

Comment: Hi viplock,ok but can you change my code according to the mentioned condition.

Comment: check the answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.forEach(vm.settings.tab_permissions, function (v, i) {
            if(v.role === vm.heading){
               v = vm.data;
            }else {
               vm.settings.tab_permissions.push(vm.data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular use `angular.foreach` like-

```
 angular.forEach(vm.settings.tab_permissions,function(value, key){
     if(value.role === vm.heading){
          value = vm.data;
        }else {
         vm.settings.tab_permissions.push(vm.data);
        }
      });
```

Check the sequence of parameter change in function , it holds value first then key

Comment: My problem is i have vm. heading as 'Agents' that lies at 4 th position in vm.settings.tab_permissions,mean while Ahents is pushed?Which is a duplicate case.

Comment: what do you mean by "while Ahents is pushed" , ? please explain with some example

Comment: Acutally agents data should be replaced with existing one,In the process of checking the  condition for agents ,the record is pushed since loop goes for 4th iteration for matching agents.

Comment: first of all never update the same array which you are using for iteration here it is `vm.settings.tab_permissions` . Don't add or remove any thing in the array while iteration. For the use add the data into some other array while iteration and if needed add it in the main array after the for each